# Interactive webapp without backend

Tags: web-applications, shiny, jupyter-notebook, reactive-programming, plotly

Can I make something like the image below without a backend?
I want to make interactive charts with user input and host it on github pages.
I tried RShiny and PlotlyDash and both work fine but require a server to work.
I'm new to webdev but I imagine this could be done only in the client side.

[image: image](https[![jupyter]

Comment: As shiny tagged here he probably means no `node.js` as backend. You can write static pages with `rmarkdown` if you want

Comment: @B001 without a server. every time someone access the page he would receive only the html+js

Comment: @PorkChop but rmarkdown does need a shinyserver to deploy.

Comment: no it doesnt need shiny server, you can choose to use it if you like but not necessary

Comment: @YuriFBecker I don't know in this specific case, but I can produce static html that behave as a webapp. It's not straightforward and sometime you have to play with buttons and `iframe` inside an html file.